# Getting the number of registered arguments of a calling convention in LLVM

Tags: llvm

I'm modifying X86FrameLowering in LLVM to add custom prologue (something similar to `X86FrameLowering::adjustForSegmentedStacks`) and I need to know the number of registered arguments (i.e., the arguments that should be assigned to registers) for the specified calling convention of the function.

How could I do that? I'm using LLVM 3.2.

Comment: I mean, is this even possible (with the current infrastructure)?